# iOS App supporting only Spanish

Tags: ios, localization

1. What i am trying to develop is the iOS app supporting only Spanish.
2. What i did is project.xcodeproj file is removed english & aded spanish [image]
3. In Info.plist file even though the option "es" was not there, i added "es" for "localization native development region"[image]
4. What i see that for story board the localisation string file got created
   [image]
5. When i run the project on simulator, what i see is the default words get display in spanish but the button text, view title get display in english[image][image]

**

Query:

1. I do not need any other language support even english only spanish, 
   am i on right track?
2. As this is something which i am developing for the first time, I will  be going through https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/ but is Main.String is the file where i need to describe spanish words for english words which is define in storyboard or controller by me for button, view title etc.

Please note: I know there are several question, docs & help on this topic but sue to some confusions, i want to make sure that i am on right track before moving further due to time constraint. Thank You

**

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/localization-tutorial-ios8/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your steps to translate the application only for spanish language is correct.
2. In Main.Strings you can translate labels defined in storyboard.

In addition, you can create the file Localizable.strings to translate the words created by code, and in your code should write this:

```
self.yourlabel.text = NSLocalizedString(<#key#>, <#comment#>);
```